# Bootstrap vertical alignment with column wrapping and different height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to present 4 div with size "col-md-6".
If all of them got the same height, all is working (the result is like there)

1 2
3 4

But if one of them (example with 1 div) is taller than others, then result change, and the 3 is not starting at the bottom of the number 3 div

I got this :

12
   2
   4
   4
3

I want this :

12
32
   4

[image]

[here- Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqOaya)

Thank you

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B<br>B</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow;">C<br>C<br>C<br>C<br>C<br>C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:purple;">D<br>D<br>D<br>D<br>D<br>D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello , Please put your code

Comment: @core114 it's juste like CodePen, not enough ?

Comment: Hello, Did you want to same size col height or that one https://jsfiddle.net/2017mb/ph34tm87/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [piece of code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aaVdLQ)

I've just added two cols in your row :

**Before :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow;">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:purple;">...</div>
</div>
```

**After :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0">
        <div style="background-color:purple;">...</div>
        <div style="background-color:red;">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0">
        <div style="background-color:green;">...</div>
        <div style="background-color:yellow;">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope answering to your request

Comment: Thank you Nicolas